# Acquire x-axis values in Python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Before I ask this question, I have already searched the internet for a while without success. To many experts this surely appears to be fairly simple. Please bear with me.

I am having a plot made by matplotlib and it is returned as a plf.Figure. See the following:

```
def myplotcode():
    x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)
    y = np.sin(x)
    print("x in external function", x)
    y2 = np.cos(x)
    fig = plf.Figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(x, y, 'bo', x, y2,'gs')
    ax.set_ylabel("Some function")
    return fig, ax
```

What I want to do in the function that call this one is to be able to get all these x values from the returned ax or fig. Well, I understand one simple solution is just to return x array too. However, I am trying to keep the number of returns as small as possible.

So, my question is: Can I acquire this x-axis array from fig or ax?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
l = ax.axes.lines[0] # If you have more curves, just change the index
x, y = l.get_data()
```

That will give you two arrays, with the `x` and `y` data

Comment: Thanks, David. This works. I searched the document of axes and didn't come across get_data().

Comment: Yeah, sometimes it is useful to use `IPython` to get most of the properties or methods in the class by using `tab`. In this case if you do `l.` and `tab` you would see all of the curve properties :)

Comment: Will take you advise seriously. Thanks a lot.